# Using Invoke-Webrequest in PowerShell 3.0 spawns a Windows Security Warning

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, powershell-3.0

When using the following code in PowerShell 3.0

```
PS> $data = Invoke-Webrequest -Uri stackoverflow.com
PS> $data.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

I get this warning:

> Windows Security Warning - To allow this website to provide information 
>   personalized for you, will you allow it to put a small file (called a cookie)
>   on your computer?

I would really like to **suppress this message or add code to handle cookies**, so the code could be scheduled.

I have tried trusting the site in IE allowing cookies and even lowering the "User Account Control Settings" but with no avail.

Answer (score 23):

```
$data = Invoke-WebRequest http://stackoverflow.com -UseBasicParsing
```

It looks like an Internet Explorer prompt, this is because under the hood Invoke-WebRequest is probably using Internet Explorer to parse the DOM. When you use the `-UseBasicParsing` parameter you instructing PowerShell to use its own parser. For some reason, it also seems to hide the cookies prompt.

Comment: If not using `-UseBasicParsing` (it messes up rest of my script), is there a way to close the Internet Explorer window sessions opened by Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: -UseBasicParsing changes the web engine to the powershell engine, and as a result you get different data back, including empty properties like .images

Answer (score 3):

The message can be suppressed by loosening the privacy setting in your internet options [image]

You can also just add a per site pricavy option for the site you're using in your script, instead of allowing all cookies.

Opposed to the `-UseBasicParsing` You'll keep the parsing provided by internet explorer. (At the cost of loosened security)

Comment: Doesn't work for me... tried allowing everything, blocking everything, changed the settings in both user and administrative mode... Some sites will spawn those warnings and some will not.