# Powershell Handling cookie popup without using invoke-webrequest

Tags: powershell, cookies

I am attempting to get a script working that does not use invoke-webrequest. The problem I am having is that when I run the script a popup prompt occurs, the popup consists of the following message;

"Windows Security Warning
To allow this website to provide information personalized for you, will you allow it to put a small file (called a cookie) on your computer?"
with yes no response from user
The code I am executing is the following:

```
$ParsedHTML = New-Object -com "HTMLFILE"
$webresponse = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webresponse.Headers.Add("Cookie", $CookieContainer.GetCookieHeader($url))
$result = $webresponse.DownloadString($url)
$ParsedHTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($webresponse)
$ParsedHTML.body.innerText
```

The main problem with this code is that the $url I am using part of the weblink checks to see if cookies are enabled and this code causes a returned value of disabled.

My question, is there a way to handle the cookie request without changing the output response from the test url site.

Note: This script will be automating a process over hundreds of remote computers and thus having an unhandled popup will just prevent the script from running.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer in another SO question [Using Invoke-Webrequest in PowerShell 3.0 spawns a Windows Security Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211573/using-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-3-0-spawns-a-windows-security-warning)

add the parameter  -UseBasicParsing

Technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx notes that the parameter stops the DOM processing. and has the caveat "This parameter is required when Internet Explorer is not installed on the computers, such as on a Server Core installation of a Windows Server operating system."

So, you mileage may vary.

Comment: In SharePoint when invoke-webrequest is used to get a people.aspx page for membership it can throw an error saying `init.js failed to load`. I found that -UseBasicParsing prevented the popup, but $result.allElements then does is not populated so I switched to using $result.rawcontent. Thanks Rob.