# Vector smash protection is enabled PowerShell

Tags: powershell

After issuing following command `Invoke-WebRequest ekonomika.idnes.cz` in PowerShell, its execution stops and I receive this message `Vector smash protection is enabled.` One of the cpu cores runs on 100% [image]

A search on google did not reveal much more information - rather the opposite. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably getting an IE prompt that looks like this:
[image]

To bypass this use the `-UseBasicParsing` switch:

```
Invoke-WebRequest ekonomika.idnes.cz -UseBasicParsing
```

Comment: Thx! Correct, I get that prompt. Could you provide more details?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211573/using-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-3-0-spawns-a-windows-security-warning