# How to parse the HTML of a website with PowerShell

Tags: html, powershell, dom, html-parsing

I am trying to retrieve some information about a website, I want to look for a specific tag/class and then return the contained text value (innerHTML). This is what I have so far

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -UseBasicParsing
$HTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
$src = $request.RawContent
$HTML.write($src)


foreach ($obj in $HTML.all) { 
    $obj.getElementsByClassName('some-class-name') 
}
```

I think there is a problem with converting the HTML into the HTML object, since I see a lot of undefined properties and empty results when I'm trying to "Select-Object" them.

So after spending two days, how am I supposed to parse HTML with Powershell?

- I can't use `IHTMLDocument2` methods, since I don't have Office installed ([Unable to use IHTMLDocument2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307976/unable-to-use-ihtmldocument2))
- I can't use the `Invoke-Webrequest` without `-UseBasicParsing` since the Powershell hangs and spawns additional windows while accessing the ParsedHTML property ([parsedhtml doesnt respond anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344462/parsedhtml-doesnt-respond-anymore) and [Using Invoke-Webrequest in PowerShell 3.0 spawns a Windows Security Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211573/using-invoke-webrequest-in-powershell-3-0-spawns-a-windows-security-warning))

So since parsing HTML with regex is such a big no-no, how do I do it otherwise? Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Check out the HTMLAgility nuget package.  It's raw .NET, but will help you immensely when dealing with HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If installing a **third-party module** is an option:

- The **[`PSParseHTML` module](https://github.com/EvotecIT/PSParseHTML)** wraps the **[HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)**,<sup>[1]</sup> and the **[AngleSharp](https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp)** .NET libraries (NuGet packages); you can use either for HTML parsing; the latter requires `-Engine AngleSharp` as an opt-in; as for their respective **DOMs (object models)**:

  - The **HTML Agility Pack**, which is used by default, provides an object model this similar to **similar to the XML DOM** provided by the standard **[`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)** NET type (`[xml]`). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60658511/45375) for an example of its use.
  - **AngleSharp**, which requires opt-in via `-Engine AngleSharp`, is built upon the official W3C specification and therefore provides a **HTML DOM as available in web browsers**. Notably, this means that its `.QuerySelector()` and `.QuerySelectorAll()` methods can be used with the usual [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_object_model/Locating_DOM_elements_using_selectors), such as shown below.
- An added advantage of using this module is that it is not just **cross-edition**, but also **cross-platform**; that is, you can use it in *Windows PowerShell* as well as in [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), and via the latter also on *Unix*-like platforms.

---

A **self-contained example** based on the **AngleSharp engine** that parses the home page of the English Wikipedia and extracts all HTML elements whose `class` attribute value is `vector-menu-content-list`:

```bash
# Install the PSParseHTML module on demand
If (-not (Get-Module -ErrorAction Ignore -ListAvailable PSParseHTML)) {
  Write-Verbose "Installing PSParseHTML module for the current user..."
  Install-Module -Scope CurrentUser PSParseHTML -ErrorAction Stop
}

# Using the AngleSharp engine, parse the home page of the English Wikipedia
# into an HTML DOM.
$htmlDom = ConvertFrom-Html -Engine AngleSharp -Url https://en.wikipedia.org

# Extract all HTML elements with a 'class' attribute value of 'vector-menu-content-list'
# and output their text content (.TextContent)
$htmlDom.QuerySelectorAll('.vector-menu-content-list').TextContent
```

Answer (score 9):

Since noone else has posted an answer, I managed to get a working solution with the following code:

```
$request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -UseBasicParsing
$HTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
[string]$htmlBody = $request.Content
$HTML.write([ref]$htmlBody)
$filter = $HTML.getElementsByClassName($htmlClassName)
```

With some URLs I experienced that the $filter variable was empty while it was populated for other URLs. All in all this might work for your situation but it seems like Powershell isn't the way to go for more complex parsing.

Comment: I would point out that this solution works only on PowerShell deployed on Windows. The COM objects are not available in PowerShell v7.x.x generally.

Comment: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24989452/11942268), if `.write()` throws an error.

Answer (score 5):

In 2020 with PowerShell 5+ you do it like this:

```bsh
$searchClass = "banana" <# in this example we parse all elements of class "banana" but you can use any class name you wish #>
$myURI = "url.com" <# replace url.com with any website you want to scrape from #>

[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12 <# using TLS 1.2 is vitally important #>
$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByClassName($searchClass) | %{Write-Host $_.innerhtml}

#for extra credit we can parse all the links
$req.ParsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('a') | %{Write-Host $_.href} #outputs all the links
```

Comment: When I look up IHTMLDocument2 I only see 2 methods, write and close.  Where is getElementsByClassName declared?  How do I find what other methods are available to  the ParsedHtml property?

Comment: in 2020 with powershell 7.0.3 this unfortunately doesn't work. 
the response ("$req") will not have a property called ParsedHtml. 
Is this a powershell-classic-only feature?

Comment: try
```$req = Invoke-Webrequest -URI $myURI -usebasicparsing```

Comment: @BenR "This parameter has been deprecated. Beginning with PowerShell 6.0.0, all Web requests use basic parsing only. This parameter is included for backwards compatibility only and any use of it has no effect on the operation of the cmdlet."